# gradle test raise error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class groovy.lang.GroovySystem

Tags: testing, groovy, gradle

I try to run "gradle test", and get error

My test is

```
class HelperTest extends ro.gd.Test {
    Plugin o;

    void setUp() {
        o = new Plugin();
    }

    void testGetIdeaDeps() {
        def r = o.ideaDeps
        asrHaveVal r
    }
}
```

when i run gradle test, it raise:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Exception in constructor: testGetIdeaDeps (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class groovy.lang.GroovySystem
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.isValidWeakMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:221)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassForClass(ClassInfo.java:191)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:236)
    at ro.gd.idea.HelperTest.$getStaticMetaClass(HelperTest.groovy)
    at ro.Test.<init>(Test.groovy)
    at ro.gd.Test.<init>(Test.groovy)
    at ro.gd.idea.HelperTest.<init>(HelperTest.groovy)
...
```

[Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B08GAyjqgToLUGNjbG52ZS1GZDQ/0B08GAyjqgToLfkdqWl9MYlc5cTRicHhtaUhHYkR2eVEzdm1xZkhHU3YxcXBSTVZrR3JmVGc) is my full code

Comment: Can you post a small reproducible example here? Can't see files on google drive from mobiles and they might vanish and then this question won't help anyone in the future with the same issue

Comment: ... or the file being simply not accessible at all, since a login is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I fix this question. the reason is "groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Conflicting module versions", for detail, following is my build.gradle

```
compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:+'
compile gradleApi()
```

I guess gradleApi() will auto "compile localGroovy()", and this groovy version is 2.3.6, but latest version is 2.4.3

I find this error message in one test report

the solution is to specify groovy version like following

```
compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.6'
```

and you check your groovy version with 'gradle dependencies|grep groovy'

Comment: I find you're almost always better off avoiding wildcard dependency versions

Comment: @tim_yates what do you mean "wildcard dependency"